# How to keep TypeDef in Proguard?

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I am trying to obfuscate TypeDef using android proguard.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@IntDef({NumberId.NUMBER_ONE, NumberId.NUMBER_TWO, NumberId.NUMBER_THREE, NumberId.NUMBER_FOUR})
public @interface NumberId {
    int NUMBER_ONE = 1;
    int NUMBER_TWO = 2;
    int NUMBER_THREE = 3;
    int NUMBER_FOUR = 4;
}
```

and proguard keep i am using is

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepclassmembers class ** {
      @<package_name>.NumberId public *;
}
```